# Where did all display resolutions go?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, resolution

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my new laptop. After testing some things with the liveCD. When I ran Ubuntu with the liveCD I could choose between a number of different resolutions for my display, but after installing Ubuntu on my hard drive there's only one option left (highest available res).

How do I get all the different resolution options back like they were presented on the liveCD?

EDIT: I just reinstalled the whole OS for a different reason, and it seems the non-proprietary graphics driver can handle different resolutions. The proprietary nvidia drivers (both 304 and 319) can only use the full resolution at 2880x1620.

EDIT2: I still got no answer to why the nvidia-drivers don't support lower resolutions, but I found a workaround. By running `xrandr --output DP-0 --scale 0.75x0.75` I can scale everything down by 25%. This makes Ubuntu usable again, even tough I loose some of the "crispness". That would be expected by running at a lower resolution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are missing graphics card drivers. Install all updates and then check the Additional Drivers program.

Comment: I've tried all three different drivers, but to no avail. But since the highest resolution available works (2880x1620) I'm guessing the graphics part of it is doing all right, it's just missing some configuration somewhere. I don't know much about xorg or it's tools so I'm lost here.